# Integrating python with quickbook desktop application

Tags: python, odoo, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using quick-books to integrate with python(ODOO). I have searched through various sources where it gives the answer for connecting with quick-books web based integration. My question is simply how to integrate and send values/create records in quick-books using python.

Python ---> quick-books desktop application

Comment: I don't know much about quickbooks, but it seems quickbooks has API support (reference https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/account#the-account-object), You can use python's request module to integrate these api in your code, https://realpython.com/python-requests/

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but this is for quickbooks online service, but I am asking for desktop.@RahulRaut

Comment: Have you checked this https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f000050UHuJCAW/api-integration-with-quickbooks-desktop?

Comment: This uses rest api and it is for online based service of quickbooks@RahulRaut

Comment: Actually the codes are not proper connecting python with quickbooks. Need to wait for the expert to answer@Santhosh

Comment: QB database is hard to deal with. One solution would be to use QODBC Driver (https://qodbc.com), with this you can read and write QB desktop database with SQL (you can use python). QODBC could be slow and may work better for overnight, not realtime transaction sync.

Comment: Is is possible to create records in QB using python?